# How to include &nbsp in openlaszlo text pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, openlaszlo, lzx

I tried this small example which is working fine but i cant give space in between word which is expected.

```
   <inputtext width="150"
    pattern="[A-Za-z0-9!@:;#$%\^*()_\-\=+/&amp;,./?&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;{}[]\\|`~ ]*">
    This text is editable.
    </inputtext>
```

But if i give

**pattern="[A-Za-z0-9!@:;#$%\^*()_-\=+/&,./?<>"' {}[]\|`~ ]*"**

it is showing error.how to include this space in text pattern.plz help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a space character instead of &nbsp; since the space is converted into an &nbsp; only after the text field received the input.

```
<canvas>

  <inputtext width="150"
    pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]*">
    This text is editable.
  </inputtext>

</canvas>
```